# Grammatical usage of prepositions: before or after "not only ....but also...."

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Which one is more universal, before or after "not only...but also..."?

I saw a sentence in an article:

> ...masters were responsible not only **for** teaching their apprentices
>   a trade **but also *for* providing** them some education...

But I thought omitting the second "for" would be fine:

> ...masters were responsible **for** not only teaching their apprentices
>   a trade **but also providing** them some education...

Comment: I guess you need the other "for" in the second sentence! Also is it "some education"?

Comment: If the gerund clauses were shorter, you could get away with it. But these clauses are too long to stretch the memory of one little preposition across; it needs a repeater to reach the second clause.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those constructs are fine. They work fine in both instances as they both as examples of correct grammar.

Try looking at [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)).